# Sort python dictionaries with 'value' as primary key and 'key' as secondary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What I am trying to do here is to display characters according to number of occurrences in a string in descending order. If two characters share the same number of occurrences, then they should be displayed as per the alphabetic order.

So given a string, 'abaddbccdd', what I want to display as output is:
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']

Here is what I have done so far:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'abaddbccdd'
>>> b = Counter(s)
>>> b
Counter({'d': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2})
>>> b.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
>>> c = sorted(b, key=b.get, reverse=True)
>>> c
['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']
>>>
```

But how to handle the second part? 'a', 'b' and 'c' all appear in the text exactly twice and are out of order. What is the best way (hopefully shortest too) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a single sorting pass. The trick is to do an ascending sort with the count numbers negated as the primary sorting key and the dictionary's key strings as the secondary sorting key.

```
b = {'d': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2}
c = sorted(b, key=lambda k:(-b[k], k))
print(c)
```

**output**

```
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way is:

```
>>> sorted(sorted(b), key=b.get, reverse=True)
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

So sort the sequence once in its natural order (the key order) then reverse sort on the values.

Note this won't have the fastest running time if the dictionary is large as it performs two full sorts, but in practice it is probably simplest because you want the values descending and the keys ascending.

The reason it works is that Python guarantees the sort to be stable. That means when the keys are equal the original order is preserved, so if you sort repeatedly from the last key back to the first you will get the desired result. Also `reverse=True` is different than just reversing the output as it also respects stability and only reverses the result where the keys are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lambda` function:

```
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda char: (b.get(char), 1-ord(char)), reverse=True)
```

Comment: That key function gives `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` with the OP's data, not `['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']`, as desired.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Sorry about that.  Now that I have edited, I'm not so sure it's a good answer.

Comment: You _could_ just do `-ord(char)`. Your solution works for the OP's purposes, but of course it wouldn't work in situations where the `dict` key isn't a single char. And of course _my_ version won't work when the `dict` values are non-numeric, although that's not an issue if `dict` is guaranteed to be a Counter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a Counter object, there is the Counter.most_common method. This will return a list of the items in order of highest to lowest frequency.

```
>>> b.most_common()
[('d', 4), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Comment: I just checked, it doesn't always return characters in proper alphabetic order (like first 'a', then 'b', and then 'c') if they share same frequency. So to ensure correctness, I would need to apply a sort on it anyway.